# Arrays in array, 100 rows, dynamic columns

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm trying to get this:

```
arrays[1][0] = 5

arrays[2][0] = 7
arrays[2][1] = 2

arrays[3][0] = 6
arrays[3][1] = 9
arrays[3][2] = 11
```

So I want `arrays[1][]` to have one element of random data, `arrays[2][]` to have 2 elements of random data and so on until I have 100 arrays. So my last array would be `arrays[100][]` with 100 elements of random data.

This is the code I have now but I get a NullPointerException when `arrays[i][j] = generator.nextInt(max)` is executed:

```
Comparable[][] arrays = new Comparable[100][];
    for (int i=1; i<101;i++){
        for (int j=0; j <= i-1; j++){
            arrays[i][j] = generator.nextInt(max);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code of `generator.nextInt(max)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your

```
Comparable[][] arrays = new Comparable[100][];
```

line only creates the *outermost* array. You need to create the arrays that go in it, e.g. something like this:

```
Comparable[][] arrays = new Comparable[100][];
for (int i=1; i<101;i++){
    arrays[i] = new Comparable[/* relevant length here*/]; // <====
    for (int j=0; j <= i-1; j++){
        arrays[i][j] = generator.nextInt(max);
    }
}
```

It's unclear to me why you start `i` at `1` or where the randomness should be (I'm guessing at `/* relevant length here */`), but hopefully that points you the right way.

Comment: Thank you, that did the job. I started i at 1 because then it's easier to read that array[1] has one element, array[2] has two elements and so on. The setup of the arrays is not random but the data that goes into it is.